# how to Check if condition in Html using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am using an HtML and PHP. I have to check the Table with the If condition using PHP
for Example

```
<?php if($status==0) {?>
<td><input type='text' name='test' id='test' value=''>
<?php }?>
<?php else (if($status==2) && ($status==1)) {?>
<td><input type='text' name='test' id='test' value=''>
<?php }?>
```

Am getting eror as unexpected else and unexpected boolean.........

Is it wrong?

Comment: It might be helpful to show some code and what you expect to get as a result... Your question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Very vague. Can you add a code snippet perhaps?

Comment: Sounds like you have a PHP syntax problem. You're going to have to post more information and a more specific question if you want help though.

Comment: @John, @Canuteson : there was a code portion, but it was not formated as such -- and, so, didn't appear ;; I've edited the question to format it properly, and the code now appears.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it seems you have two syntax errors.

First, the following lines :

```
<?php } ?>
<?php else (if($status==2) && ($status==1)) { ?>
```

Should go in only one PHP tag : there should be no closing + beginning tags between the `}` and the `else`.

Second, the opening parenthesis should not be between the `else` and the `if` -- but arround the condition :

```
<?php } else if(($status==2) && ($status==1)) { ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

While the others have covered your syntax error, I'll cover your logic error:

```
<?php } else if(($status==2) && ($status==1)) { ?>
```

This checks to see if `$status` is equal to 2, and then also checks that `$status` is equal to 1.

`$status` can't be *both* 1 **and** 2 at the same time.

If `$status` is 1, then the `if` check evaluates to:

```
<?php } else if((false) && (true)) { ?>
```

... which is `false`, meaning the condition won't match.

You probably want `||`, the "logical or" operator instead of `&&`, the "logical and" operator:

```
<?php } else if(($status==2) || ($status==1)) { ?>
```

[Here's the PHP manual page on logical operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Answer (score 0):

Here is syntax error

```
<?php else (if($status==2) && ($status==1)) {?>
```

Change it to

```
<?php elseif(($status==2) && ($status==1)) {?>
```

**EDIT**

Space is not allowed between [elseif](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php). Also you have logical error as others pointed change your `&&` to `||`

> Note: Note that elseif and else if
>   will only be considered exactly the
>   same when using curly brackets When using a colon
>   to define your if/elseif conditions,
>   you must not separate else if into two
>   words, or PHP will fail with a parse
>   error.

```
<?php if ($vCertificateStatus==0):?> 
<td><input type="text" name="CertificateDate" id="CertificateDate" value="" /> 
<?php elseif(($vCertificateStatus==-1) || ($vCertificateStatus==1)):?> 
<td><input type="text" name="CertificateDate" id="CertificateDate" value="<?php echo $vReceivedDate;?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This is my code  <?php if ($vCertificateStatus==0) :?>
   <td><input type="text" name="CertificateDate" id="CertificateDate" value="" />
   <?php else if(($vCertificateStatus==-1)&&($vCertificateStatus==1)) :?>
   <td><input type="text" name="CertificateDate" id="CertificateDate" value="<?php echo $vReceivedDate;?>" />
   <?php endif; ?> still i am getting error as syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ':'

Comment: @akila: If it is working and helped you Please accept my answer by clicking on the right arrow sign.

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error while saying else if.... I would rewrite the code as following:

```
<?php if($status==0) :?>
<td><input type='text' name='test' id='test' value=''>
<?php else if (($status==2) && ($status==1)) :?>
<td><input type='text' name='test' id='test' value=''>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This is my code <?php if ($vCertificateStatus==0) :?> <td><input type="text" name="CertificateDate" id="CertificateDate" value="" /> <?php else if(($vCertificateStatus==-1)&&($vCertificateStatus==1)) :?> <td><input type="text" name="CertificateDate" id="CertificateDate" value="<?php echo $vReceivedDate;?>" /> <?php endif; ?> still i am getting error as syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ':'

Comment: yeah definitely its your code with slidght modification on else if and instead of {} i am using :

Answer (score 0):

Insteed of {...} you need to use : and endif;

```html
<?php if($status==0) :?>
<td><input type='text' name='test' id='test' value=''>

<?php elseif(($status==2) && ($status==1)) :?>
<td><input type='text' name='test' id='test' value=''>
<?php endif; ?>
```

?>